# Using button_press_event to draw seperate lines on a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling, line

I would like to use button_press_events to draw lines on a plot.
The following code does that, but the line coordinates follows on each other.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# Plot some random data
values = np.random.rand(4,1);
graph_1, = ax.plot(values, label='original curve')
graph_2, = ax.plot([], marker='.')

# Keep track of x/y coordinates
xcoords = []
ycoords = []

def onclick(event):
    xcoords.append(event.xdata)
    ycoords.append(event.ydata)

    # Update plotted coordinates
    graph_2.set_xdata(xcoords)
    graph_2.set_ydata(ycoords)

    # Refresh the plot
    fig.canvas.draw()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How do I separate the events so every second click results in a separate line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.
Note that there are many things that should be improved in this code, such as detecting whether the click was detected inside or outside the axes, but it should put you on the right track.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# Plot some random data
values = np.random.rand(4,1);
graph_1, = ax.plot(values, label='original curve')

# Keep track of x/y coordinates
lines = []
xcoords = []
ycoords = []

def onclick(event):
    xcoords.append(event.xdata)
    ycoords.append(event.ydata)
    if len(xcoords)==2:
        lines.append(ax.plot(xcoords,ycoords,'.-'))
        xcoords[:] = []
        ycoords[:] = []

    # Refresh the plot
    fig.canvas.draw()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

[image]